# What does eval X=\$$i mean in UNIX?

Tags: scripting, solaris, eval

I have a small script with the following lines

```
echo mom,dad |awk -F, '{print $1,$2}' | while read VAR1 VAR2
do
 for i in VAR1 VAR2
  do
   eval X=\$$i
   echo $X
 done  
done
```

OUTPUT:

```
mom
dad
```

What is this line doing `eval X=\$$i`?

I understand the rest of the lines, but I don't understand the iterations of this for loop with eval. Can someone shed light on this ? I am using Solaris 5.10 with Korn Shell.

Comment: Jeff Schaller has a good explanation of what's going on.  It's possible to get this same effect without `eval` by replacing the eval line with `X=${!i}` which will assign to `X` the value of the variable whose name is stored in `i`

Comment: @EricRenouf Thanks.How does X=${!i} work, can you break it down little further ?

Comment: `${}` is a general syntax for accessing a variable (though it can often be shortened to $varname).  You can do many things within the `{}` to affect the variable access, one of which is if the first character in `{}` is `!` the rest is another variable name (`i` in this example) then the value in that other variable (`i`) will be expanded and treated as the name of the variable to access with the `${}`, so if `i=VAR1` then `${!i}` becomes `${VAR1}` which is the same as `$VAR1`

Comment: @EricRenouf Thank you..makes more sense now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`eval` performs an extra level of substitution and processing on the remainder of the line.

In the first iteration of the loop, i is set to "VAR1", and one level of backslash-escaping is reduced, so:

```
eval X=\$$i
```

becomes:

```
X=$VAR1
```

which evaluates to:

```
X=mom
```

(repeat for the next loop, only $i is then VAR2, and $VAR2=dad)